# Problemas ao passar parametro URL

Tags: php, url

No código abaixo, como faço para pegar os valores do `input` `IdObra` e `IdCliente` e passar pela url `<a href="<?=base_url("/index.php/ProdutosObras")?>"`? Estou utilizando um modal.

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="geraisObras" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" type="text" class="form-control" id="idObra" name="idObra" value="idObra">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" type="text" class="form-control" id="clienteObra" name="clienteObra" value="clienteObra">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">

        <label for="nomeObra">Nome Obra</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomeObra" autofocus name="nomeObra">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="valorObra">Valor Obra</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valorObra" name="valorObra">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipoObra">Tipo Obra</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tipoObra" name="tipoObra">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">  
        <label>Status Obra</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="statusObra" id="statusObra">
            <option value="Em andamento">Em andamento</option>
            <option value="Finalizada">Finalizada</option>
            <option value="Parada">Parada</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="clienteObras" class="tab-pane fade">
    <?php

        echo "<div class='form-group' type='hidden'>";
        echo "<label hidden>Cliente</label>";
        echo "<select  class='form-control' name='clienteObra' id='clienteObra'>";
        foreach ($clientes as $cliente):
        {
          echo "<option value='$cliente[id_cliente]'>$cliente[nomeCliente]</option>";
        }
        endforeach;
        echo "</select>";
        echo "</div>";
    ?>
</div>

<div id="produtosObras" class="tab-pane fade">
    <a href="<?=base_url("/index.php/ProdutosObras")?>" class="button" target="_blank">Adicionar Produtos</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Porque o tipo do campo 'IdObra' está hidden ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No evento `onclick` são atribuídos às respectivas chaves dos parâmetros  os valores recuperados através da função do JavaScript `document.getElementById` que serve para retornar um elemento do DOM que é identificado por um ID específico.

```
<a href='' onclick="this.href='<?=base_url("/index.php/ProdutosObras")?>?p='+document.getElementById('idObra').value+'&q='+document.getElementById('clienteObra').value">update</a>
```

> Não sei se essa parte `<?=base_url("/index.php/ProdutosObras")?>` está correta, aliás, nunca tinha visto isso antes. Porém fiz um teste com o exemplo abaixo onde substituo `<?=base_url("/index.php/ProdutosObras")?>` por `https://pt.stackoverflow.com` e funciona bem:

```
<input type="hidden" type="text" class="form-control" id="idObra" name="idObra" value="Value_idObra">
<input type="hidden" type="text" class="form-control" id="clienteObra" name="clienteObra" value="Value_clienteObra">

<a href='' onclick="this.href='https://pt.stackoverflow.com?p='+document.getElementById('idObra').value+'&q='+document.getElementById('clienteObra').value">update</a>
```

Comment: Sua resposta está na fila de análise de publicações de baixa qualidade, provavelmente porque não tem nenhum texto e só um código. Vou clicar no botão "Parece OK", mas eu sugiro a você editar a resposta para colocar um pouco de texto nela.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, botão? que botão é esse?

Comment: Esse daqui: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWwCi.png

Comment: Hehehe, entendi

Comment: Ola, obrigado pelo retorno. Mas o que vem como valor é simplesmente idObra e clienteObra e não os valores que estão nos inputs.

Comment: Resolvido. muito obrigado. a solução postada está ok.

Comment: os valores que estão nos inputs também  são idObra e clienteObra, alterei no exemplo para Value_idObra e Value_clienteObra

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar um evento de click nesse botão e fazer uma função com javascript para concatenar os valores dos inputs com a url, por exemplo :

```
<button onclick="produtosObras()" id="btnUrl" href="<?=base_url("/index.php/ProdutosObras/")?>" class="button" target="_blank">Adicionar Produtos</button>

<script>
   function produtosObras(){

      var url = document.querySelector("#btnUrl").getAttribute('href');

      url += '/?idObra=' + document.querySelector('#IdObra').value;
      url += '/&idCliente=' + document.querySelector('#IdCliente').value;

      window.location.href = url;

   } 
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.